# virtualenv removing libraries (flask / yolk) on restart

Tags: python, flask, virtualenv, yolk

I just started learning Flask (and as a result, getting into `virtualenv` as well). I followed a tutorial on Flask's documentation and created a small application. I installed Flask and yolk using `venv` and everything was working fine.

I restarted my computer and when I activated `virtualenv` again, flask and yolk were no longer recognised. I had to reinstall them via `easy_install`. Does `venv` remove any installed packages once the computer has been restarted?

What happened here? Is there anything I need to do from my side?

Comment: Does it happens with only one virtualenv or all of them?

Comment: I only created one virtualenv and restarted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you're sourcing the virtualenv correctly and installing the packages correctly, your virtualenv should not be affected by a reboot. It's completely independent of that. There are one of three possibilities that I can think of that explains your issues:

1. The incorrect virtualenv was sourced
2. You installed flask and yolk onto the system python
3. You used some kind of ephemeral storage

(The third is the least likely)

Comment: If I installed flask and yolk onto the system python, then running `which yolk` and `which flask` would yield the path to the file in `bin`. I got nothing as a result. I only have one virtualenv installed so that also takes point #1 out?

Comment: Did you make sure to source that virtualenv?

Comment: I realised I had yolk and flask installed onto the system python. The reason being is I ran `pip` with `sudo` because I am getting a `error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask': Permission denied` once I run `pip install flask` when virtualenv is activated. How can I overcome this?

Comment: My suggestion would be to remove your virtualenv. So if you're on unix or linux just ``rm -rf path_to_your_virtualenv``. Rebuild the virtualenv (do not use sudo) and then it should work.